# error C2679: binary ' >> : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'GradeType'

Tags: c++, arrays, input

Im having trouble understanding why I am getting this error message when I try to assign input into 'grades' array. There is also a message saying "IntelliSense: no operator " >> " matches these operands, operand types are: std::istream >> GradeType". Any help or tips please. Thank You in advance.

```
 // This program will input an undetermined number of student names
    // and a number of grades for each student. The number of grades is 
    // given by the user. The grades are stored in an array.
    // Two functions are called for each student. 
    // One function will give the numeric average of their grades.
    // The other function will give a letter grade to that average. 
    // Grades are assigned on a 10 point spread.  
    // 90-100 A   80- 89 B  70-79 C   60-69 D   Below 60 F

    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;


    const  int MAXGRADE = 25;              // maximum number of grades per student
    const  int MAXCHAR = 30;              // maximum characters used in a name


    typedef char StringType30[MAXCHAR + 1];// character array data type used for names 
                                           // having 30 characters or less.
    typedef  float GradeType[MAXGRADE];    // one dimensional integer array data type

    float findGradeAvg(GradeType, int);    // finds grade average by taking array of 
                                           // grades and number of grades as parameters

    char  findLetterGrade(float);          // finds letter grade from average given 
                                           // to it as a parameter


    int main()

    {
        StringType30 firstname, lastname;  // two arrays of characters defined
        int numOfGrades;                   // holds the number of grades
        GradeType  grades;                 // grades is defined as a one dimensional array 
        float average;                     // holds the average of a student's grade
        char moreinput;                    // determines if there is more input

        // Input the number of grades for each student

        cout << "Please input the number of grades each student will receive." << endl
             << "This number must be a number between 1 and " << MAXGRADE << " inclusive" << endl;

        cin >> numOfGrades;

        while (numOfGrades > MAXGRADE || numOfGrades < 1)
        {
            cout << "Please input the number of grades for each student." << endl
                 << "This number must be a number between 1 and " << MAXGRADE << " inclusive" << endl;

            cin >> numOfGrades;

        }

        // Input names and grades for each student

        cout << "Please input a y if you want to input more students"
             << " any other character will stop the input" << endl;
        cin >> moreinput;

        while ( moreinput == 'y' || moreinput == 'Y')

        {
            cout << "Please input the first name of the student" << endl;
            cin >> firstname;
            cout << endl << "Please input the last name of the student" << endl;
            cin >> lastname;

            for (int count = 0; count < numOfGrades; count++)

            {

                cout << endl << "Please input a grade" << endl;

                cin >> grades;
                    // Fill in the input statement to place grade in the array

            }

            cout << firstname << ' ' << lastname << " has an average of "; 

            cout << findGradeAvg; // Fill in code to get and print average of student to screen
            cout << findLetterGrade;// Fill in call to get and print letter grade of student to screen

            cout << endl << endl << endl;
            cout << "Please input a y if you want to input more students"
                 << " any other character will stop the input" << endl;
            cin >> moreinput;

        }

        return 0;
    }

    //***********************************************************************
    //                              findGradeAvg
    //
    //  task:           This function finds the average of the 
    //                  numbers stored in an array.
    //            
    //  data in:        an array of integer numbers
    //  data returned:  the average of all numbers in the array
    //
    //***********************************************************************

    float findGradeAvg(GradeType array, int numgrades)

    {

        float sum = 0;
        for (int pos = 0; pos < numgrades; pos++)
        {
            sum = sum + array[pos];
        }
        return (sum / numgrades); // Fill in the code for this function


    }

    //***********************************************************************
    //                              findLetterGrade
    //
    //  task:           This function finds the letter grade for the number
    //                  passed to it by the calling function
    //            
    //  data in:        a floating point number
    //  data returned:  the grade (based on a 10 point spread) of the number 
    //                  passed to the function
    //
    //***********************************************************************

    char  findLetterGrade(float numgrade)

    {

        if (numgrade >= 90 && numgrade <= 100)
        {
            return 'A';
        }
        if (numgrade >= 80 && numgrade <= 89)
        {
            return 'B';
        }
        if (numgrade >= 70 && numgrade <= 79)// Fill in the code for this function
        {
            return 'C';
        }
        if (numgrade >= 60 && numgrade <= 69)
        {
            return 'D';
        }
        else
        {
            return 'F';
        }

    }
```

Comment: Arrays in C++ are special in lots of ways. Your `GradeType` typedef masks the fact that you have an array, from humans if not the compiler, which is likely to make your code very hard to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grades` is an array.

So, use

```
cin >> grades[count];
```

Could be more issues

Comment: Thank You. I remember now why it didn't work. Guess I was overthinking it.